# Why Kotlin return Deferred<{Comparable & java.io.Serializable}> instead of Deferred<String>?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, spring-data-r2dbc

Acording to intellij and gradle, this variable `a` type is `Deferred<{Comparable  & java.io.Serializable}>`:

```
val a = async(IO) { possibleIdDeferred.await()?.also { repo.findAttrById(it) } ?: run { "" } }
```

where `possibleIdDeferred` is `Deferred<Long?>` and this is the repo function:

```
@Cacheable("someCacheName")
suspend fun findAttrById(id: Long) = entityRepo.findById(id)!!.someAttr
```

where `entityRepo` declaration is

```
@Repository
interface EntityRepo : CoroutineCrudRepository<Entity, Long> {
    suspend fun findByAttr(attr: String): Entity?
}
```

If I add `as String` as here:

```
val a = async(IO) { possibleIdDeferred.await()?.also { repo.findAttrById(it) as String} ?: run { "" as String} }
```

I get `[USELESS_CAST] No cast needed`. If I try `a.await() as String` I get `[CAST_NEVER_SUCCEEDS] This cast can never succeed`. What should I change to make variable `a` type String?

Comment: If the `async` call above is supposed to return `repo.findAttrById(it)` as a result, then you're using wrong scoping function - replace `also` with `let` (see: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#function-selection)

Comment: @Guest21 damn, you're right. With `also ?: run` I was returning  `Long? :? String`. What I really wanted was `let`. Thanks for noticing what I wanted instead of what I asked. If you wish, please fill up an answer for me to accept it. If you don't, I intend to edit this question to point out the different return types my confusion was about :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `also` returns its own context, I had

```
val a = someNullableInt ?: emptyString
```

leading to this strange type on question title. I fixed it changing `also` to `let`, since what I really wanted returned was the last statement